# Wifi Adapter not Found for Ubuntu 18.04 Lenovo v14-ADA

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, lenovo

I have tried many approach to install driver for my laptop, but still nothing have worked. First I try to find my network controller by hitting `lspci`, then the output came as follows,

```
Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device c822
```

I have cloned the rtl8821ce driver using the following link, [1]: https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce, and have run the following codes,

```
sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms
sudo m-a prepare
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Before that, I have disable the secure boot. after rebooting, I check: same as before. I also tried with `modprobe` command and many other approaches. So, nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
https://www.muchen.ca/blog/2020/ubuntu-realtek-wifi-setup/

If you have any questions feel free to reach out.Realtek drivers are a pain in the ass in ubuntu

Comment: Could you summarise that solution within your answer in case the link breaks at some point? Thank you.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210124181836/https://www.muchen.ca/blog/2020/ubuntu-realtek-wifi-setup/ (in case its dead or google cache) @Will

Comment: @ace linking without explaining is against the rules here I think. Will is right with his comment. Instead of thyping an incomplete solution you should have written a comment only